# Creating a UInt8 Fails in App but Procceeds in Playground

Tags: swift, uint

I have converted an Objective-C script to Swift for forming header of an AAC frame. However the code fails to run in the app and crashes with  an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Copying the code in to playground outputs what I expect with no errors. Not sure where to go with this, because it seems like it should work. I could always use the Objective-C version but that feels like going around the issue.

[image]

```
func adtsDataForPacketLength(packetLength: Int) -> NSData {
    let adtsLength = 7
    let profile = 2
    let freqIdx = 4
    let chanCfg = 1
    let fullLength = adtsLength + packetLength;

    var packet = [UInt8]()
    packet.append(UInt8(0xFF))
    packet.append(UInt8(0xF9))
    packet.append(UInt8(((profile-1)<<6) + (freqIdx<<2) + (chanCfg>>2)))
    packet.append(UInt8(((chanCfg&3)<<6) + (fullLength>>11)))
    packet.append(UInt8((fullLength&0x7FF) >> 3))
    packet.append(UInt8(((fullLength&7)<<5) + 0x1F))
    packet.append(0xFC)
    return NSData(bytes: packet, length: packet.count)
}
```

Comment: I could not replicate the failure here, did you test run just this lines in a blank project to check it?

Comment: @UlyssesR I just did and I couldn't either

Comment: From what I can tell it has to do with what thread I'm on. I've tested on the main thread and it worked fine. However when I ran it the AVAudio thread from a callback it failed. Also porting the method to Objective-C and running it from the same line worked

Comment: Can you try breakpoint before the error, and step by step in to try to get more info?

Comment: @UlyssesR After stepping through it I can tell that the `UInt8` is getting created but the `append` method is what is failing

Comment: it may sound ridiculous but as a last resource... can you try use insert at position, and see what happens. (another crazy idea, check the size of this UInt8 in this thread is this really 8bits...?)

Comment: @UlyssesR That doesn't sound too insane... I'll check it now

Comment: @UlyssesR calling `sizeof` within the code causes the same crash. If I stop early and call `sizeof(UInt8)` in the debugger I get `1`. Also `insert:atIndex` crashed as well.

Comment: Ok, last shot, as you have a static size,  try to code it in one single line, and see if it works (you could use let in this case) :

  var packet = [UInt8(0xFF),
                      UInt8(0xF9),
                      UInt8(((profile-1)<<6) + (freqIdx<<2) + (chanCfg>>2)),
                      UInt8(((chanCfg&3)<<6) + (fullLength>>11)),
                      UInt8((fullLength&0x7FF) >> 3),
                      UInt8(((fullLength&7)<<5) + 0x1F),
                      0xFC]

Comment: @UlyssesR actually sorry to say but that was the first thing I tried...